java parallel streams to exclude main thread as worker thread
Does Java parallel stream process all substreams in worker threads, I see the main thread is also used as a worker thread.
Sample program:
package org.example;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class StreamBasic {
    private AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamBasic streamBasic = new StreamBasic();
        streamBasic.test();
    }
    
    private void test() {
        int[] nums = {1, 2, 3};
        System.out.println("start" + "-" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Arrays.stream(nums)
                .parallel()
                .map(n -> {
                    try {
                        for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            System.out.println(n + "-" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
                    n *= 2;
                    atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
                    return n;
                })
                .toArray();
    
        System.out.println("end" + "-" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

The output shows that the parallel processing uses two worker threads and the main thread itself.
start-main
1-ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
3-main
2-ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
3-main
1-ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
2-ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
end-main
Is there way to exclude the main thread as a worker thread?

And reason you want to do this is?

If you could do this, your main thread would just be blocked waiting for the stream to complete. Why have the main thread do nothing when it could help execute the stream? If the stream was sequential the main thread would be doing all the work. Does the main thread being involved when the stream is parallel break something in your case?

If all substreams are processed by worker threads, the main thread can move on and do something else.

It can't, as that's not how the stream API is designed. The terminal operation, like forEzch, reduce, collect, etc., cannot return until the stream's execution completes, regardless of if the stream is sequential or parallel. I suppose you could submit the stream operation to a thread pool, perhaps the common fork-join pool. That will leave the main thread free to do other work. Later, you could get the result of the stream operation from the returned future.
